# JAXWS wsimport catalog to resolve "element" already defined Error

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, xjc, catalog, wsimport

We are trying to consume a web service which is hosted by the third party. When I tried to generate the artifcats & JAXB classes using wsimport, I ran in to following errors.
Please note that bothe xsd file contents are exactly similar(not sure why one would do that), including the namespace. However the 
last part servdocoid is different. The structure of wsdl and schema will follow.

```
[ERROR] 'ElementX' is already defined
  line # of http:/....:port/wsdl/schema1.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=<b>5</b>

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line # of http:/....:port/wsdl/schema1.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=<b>1</b>
```

I guess I know what the problem is and I am trying to find a work around using `-catalog with wsimport(not sure If that is the right thing to do) but still running in to error.

The wsdl strucutre is as described and I have highlighted only the key parts and ignored rest
of the wsdl definition

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http:/xyz.com" xmlns:soap12="http:/schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/ xmlns:wsdl="http:/schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http:/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
<!-- relevant -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schema1" xmlns:wsdl="http:/schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http:/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:soap12="http:/schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="http:/domain.com:port/wsdl/schema1.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=1" />
</xsd:schema>
...............
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Schema used in the above wsdl is nested, meaning it inturn imports multiple schemas which again can import mutiples. Assume it as a chain.

**schema1.xsd**

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http:/schema1" xmlns:tns1="http:/schema1" xmlns:tns2="http:/schema2" xmlns:tns3="http:/schema3" xmlns:xsd="http:/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
....
<!-- relevant -->
<xsd:import namespace="http:/schema2" schemaLocation="http:/domain.com:port/wsdl/schema2.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=2" /> 
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schema3" schemaLocation="http:/domain.com:port/wsdl/schema3.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=3" /> 
...
</xsd:schema>
```

**schema2.xsd**

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http:/schema2" xmlns:tns2="http:/schema2" xmlns:tns4="http://schema4"  xmlns:xsd="http:/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
<!-- relevant -->
 <xsd:import namespace="http:/schema4" schemaLocation="http:/domain.com:port/wsdl/schema4.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=4" /> 
...
</xsd:schema>
```

**schema4.xsd**

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http:/schema4" xmlns:tns4="http:/schema2" xmlns:tns1="http:/schema1"  xmlns:xsd="http:/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
<!-- relevant -->
 <xsd:import namespace="http:/schema1" schemaLocation="http:/domain.com:port/wsdl/schema1.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=5" /> 
...
</xsd:schema>
```

So the key schemas here are schema1.xsd and schema4.xsd. Both has exactly same contents but has differernt links. Having said that,  I'm trying to use the -catalog file to let wsimport know that for all the namespaces "http:/schema1" always resolve to one link http:/domain.com:port/wsdl/schema1.xsd?serviceoid=123&servdocoid=1
 but still I cannot get it working.

Comment: The wsimport worked with -catalog option. If you run in to similar issues, Please check your catalog file . My catalog file had a typo and wsimport ignored the xml parsing error in the catalog file. I can see that wsimport started using xsd's in my local as opposed to the one on the remote location. However, I am still running in to the same problem as before but this time using the local xsd. [ERROR] 'ElementX' is already defined line # of file:/c:/wsdl/app.xsd [ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here line # of file:/c:/wsdl/app.xsd Thanks Dev